# Можно ли подставить тип в обобщённый метод, если тип заранее не известен (.NET 4.8)?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.8

Допустим есть обобщённый метод, который в зависимости от типа значения делает преобразование в строку:

```
string ValueToString<T>(object value)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(decimal))
        return $"{value:N2}";
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
        return $"{value:dd-MM-yyyy}";
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        return $"'{value}'";

    return null;
}
```

Использование метода:

```
public Main()
{
    //например, есть таблица, содержащая колонки с разными типами данных
    DataTable t=new DataTable();
    t.Columns.Add("NO", typeof(decimal));
    t.Columns.Add("DATE", typeof(DateTime));
    t.Columns.Add("COMMENTS", typeof(string));
    t.Rows.Add(10.5, DateTime.Now, "value 1");
    t.Rows.Add(20.7, DateTime.Now, "value 2");
    t.Rows.Add(30.9, DateTime.Now, "value 3");

    //когда я хочу преобразовать значения ячеек в строку с помощью обобщающего метода начинаются проблемы
    var str=t.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(r =>
        t.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Select(c =>
        {
            //ПРИХОДИТСЯ ДЕЛАТЬ ТАК, НО ЕСЛИ ТИПОВ ЗНАЧИТЕЛЬНО БОЛЬШЕ, ТО КОД РАЗРАСТАЕТСЯ
            if (c.DataType == typeof(decimal))
                return ValueToString<decimal>(r[c]);
            else if (c.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                return ValueToString<DateTime>(r[c]);
            else if (c.DataType == typeof(string))
                return ValueToString<string>(r[c]);
            else
                return "";

            //НЕ РАБОТАЕТ!
            return ValueToString<c.DataType>(r[c]);

            
        }).ToArray()
    );
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы можно было сразу подставить тип данных столбца в обобщающий метод, чтобы не приходилось делать ветвление для каждого типа?

Comment: Из переменной нельзя. Явно надо указывать

Comment: Добавьте используемую версию .NET.

Comment: Внёс корректировки, благодарю ёмкие ответы!

Comment: `<c.DataType>` в таких скобках указывается тип, известный на этапе компилации, то есть либо обобщение, либо конкретный тип, его имя. У вас же здесь рантайм поле. поэтому и не работает.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, теперь всё ясно!

Answer (score 1):

Код можно переписать, не используя параметр типа `<T>`. В итоге метод перестаёт быть обобщённым.

```
string ValueToString(object value)
{
    if (value.GetType() == typeof(decimal))
        return $"{value:N2}";
    else if (value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
        return $"{value:dd-MM-yyyy}";
    else if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
        return $"'{value}'";

    return null;
}
```

---

В более новых версиях языка и фреймворка доступен паттерн-матчинг.
С его помощью код метода можно переписать проще и лаконичнее:

```
string? ValueToString(object value)
{
    if (value is decimal)
        return $"{value:N2}";
    else if (value is DateTime)
        return $"{value:dd-MM-yyyy}";
    else if (value is string)
        return $"'{value}'";

    return null;
}
```

Или ещё лучше:

```
string? ValueToString(object value)
{
    return value switch
    {
        decimal => $"{value:N2}",
        DateTime => $"{value:dd-MM-yyyy}",
        string => $"'{value}'",
        _ => null
    };
}
```

Совсем хорошо (используем Expression body):

```
string? ValueToString(object value) =>
    value switch
    {
        decimal => $"{value:N2}",
        DateTime => $"{value:dd-MM-yyyy}",
        string => $"'{value}'",
        _ => null
    };
```

Смотрите документацию: [Patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns).

Возвращаемый тип меняем на `string?` - nullable.

---

Теперь обобщение в методе `ValueToString<T>` не используется.
В итоге код linq-выражения упрощается кардинально:

```
var str = t.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(r =>
    t.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Select(c => ValueToString(r[c])));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", str));
```

Тип совсем не нужно указывать.

Это выражение тоже можно упростить:

```
var str = t.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(row => 
    row.ItemArray.Select(x => ValueToString(x)));
```

И ещё лучше:

```
var str = t.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(row => 
    row.ItemArray.Select(ValueToString));
```

Comment: В плане упрощения запроса Вы полностью правы, правда, использование паттернов не доступно в .NET 4.8 Возможно, мой пример был не самый удачный, чтобы описать данную проблему, но меня именно интересовало как подставить тип колонки DataColumn в метод, в котором есть <T>. По всей видимости это невозможно. В любом случае, большая благодарность за подробный ответ!

Comment: если можете, объясните, почему данный метод не является обобщённым? Каким анализатором Вы пользуетесь, в каком окне Visual Studio это видно?

Comment: @Вячеслав - виноват. Я сперва переписал метод на паттерн-матчинг, затем анализатор сообщил об этом. Сейчас исправлю ответ.

Comment: Обычный switch-case прокатит и на старых дотнетах